# Failed to load virtual device on Android Studio on mac

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

Just started with the android tutorial and I'm trying to create a virtual device but I am always getting this error message.

[image]

I tried searching but couldn't find a solution to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider using [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/), which is an android *emulator*, rather than a whole virtual device. Because it is just an emulation, it works much quicker for me!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip. Can I integrate it with android studio?

Comment: Sure, when running your app (by choosing the green play icon), choose "running device" and choose the device you are running in genymotion. Check "Genymotion Plugin for Android Studio" in the [Genymotion documentation](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide)

Comment: Thanks, I made the normal virtual device work but I like Genymotion better. :)

Comment: @Angersmash what did you do to fix the issue? I have the same problem but i don't want to use Genymotion.

Comment: @AndreeWille Hey, it was a long time back so I actually don't remember what I did. I think I installed everything again  and it magically worked. I still ended up using genymotion. I will look at it once again and will here if I find something else.

Comment: @Angersmash thank you for your answer. I fixed it by restarting Android Studio. Was quite easy ;-)